# undefined method `todo_lists' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im in progress of developing a todolist app which the app will only show a user's todo list based on their user_id. Which means if a user logged in, the database will only show the todo list with the same user_id.

but im getting this error:

```
undefined method `todo_lists' for nil:NilClass

  # GET /todo_lists/new
def new
@todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.build
end
  # GET /todo_lists/1/edit
```

todo_lists_controller.rb

```
class TodoListsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_todo_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
@todo_lists = TodoList.all
end

def new
@todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.build
end

def create
@todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.build(todo_list_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @todo_list.save
    format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was 
successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

private
def set_todo_list
  @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id])
end

def todo_list_params
  params.require(:todo_list).permit(:title, :description)
 end
end
```

got other method like destroy, update, show and edit but i dont paste it here cuz i think it has nothing to do with this problem. i tried to change the `todo_lists` to other, like `@todo_lists`, `TodoLists` and `todo_list` but none of them work.

I search for the solution in various site but i dont find any. I really think that the main problem here is that i dont understand what code to write cuz i have different code with the same meaning like i stated above (`@todo_lists` and others). Kinda stupid but yeah, still tryin' here

P/S 2 months of learning rails ^^' sry for my broken english

Comment: Can you paste what's the method definition of `current_user` ? Basically you need to debug `current_user`

Comment: @AnkitG u mean the `def current_user`? in the controller?

Comment: Yes, however you have defined `current_user`. Your `current_user` is `nil`.

Comment: im using devise, as the @seaify said, i have to add `before_action :authenticate_user!` in the controller and it work! yours is applicable to scaffold i think. Thanks anyway though ! its not work for devise but it may work for other method (on creating a user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `current_user` is nil.

If you are using `devise`, add `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your `TodoListsController`.

If not, then add similar code to your application_helper.rb

```
def current_user
   User.first
end
```

Comment: im using devise and added the `before_action :authenticate_user!`.. it means that only authenticate user can create a todolist, right?

Comment: yes, if user not login, he will be redirect to login page.